# Is it truthy or falsy?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, classification

[There are so many different ways to express whether something is true or not!](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey) The goal of this challenge is to produce a [standardized](https://xkcd.com/927/) output of `truthy` or `falsy` for various input truthy and falsy values.

For the purposes of this challenge, the following inputs are considered truthy:

1. A string representing a signed integer with a non-zero value (contains only the digits `[0-9]`, with an optional `-` at the beginning). Note that the string `-0` will never be given as input. A non-zero integer will never be preceded by a `0` (i.e. `01` will never be given as input, similarly `-01` will never be gien as input).
2. The case-insensitive strings equivalent to one of `defined`, `found`, `nonnil`, `non-nil`, `on`, `success`, `t`, `true`, `y`, and `yes`

For the purposes of this challenge, the following inputs are considered falsy:

1. The string `0`. Repeated zeros (`00`, `00...`) will never be given as input.
2. An empty string
3. The case-insensitive strings equivalent to one of `f`, `failure`, `false`, `n`, `nan`, `nil`, `no`, `notfound`, `not-found`, `null`, `nullptr`, `off`, and `undefined`

## Input

The input is a string representing a truthy/falsy value. The string may come from any source desired (stdio, function parameter, etc.). There is no leading/trailing whitespace.

The input is guaranteed to match one of the allowed truthy/falsy values above (i.e. you do not need to provide any error handling).

## Output

Your program/function must output a truthy/falsy value which represents the "truthy-ness" or "falsy-ness" of the input.
You are only allowed to specify exactly 1 truthy and 1 falsy value which your output must convert the input to (these are your "standardized" truthy/falsy value). The output may be written to any sink desired (stdio, return value, output parameter, etc.).

Please specify what `truthy` and `falsy` value you chose in your answer.

Ex.: If you choose the string `true` as a truthy value, you cannot also have the integer `1` for truthy.

## Test Cases

Test cases are formatted as the first line is the input, and the second line is the output.

```
-1
true

1
true

1234
true

-4321
true

defined
true

deFined
true

Found
true

nonnil
true

non-nil
true

ON
true

SuCCess
true

T
true

true
true

y
true

YeS
true

0
false

'' (empty string)
false

faLSE
false

f
false

Failure
false

n
false

NaN
false

nil
false

no
false

notfound
false

not-Found
false

NULL
false

nullptr
false

OFF
false

unDefined
false
```

## Scoring

This is code-golf; shortest code in bytes wins. Standard loopholes apply. You may use any built-ins desired.

Comment: Can a positive integer begin with `0`?

Comment: Are repeated zeros like `00` truthy, or are they even valid inputs? (I suppose they are not valid, but just checking)

Comment: What about [FileNotFound](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_)? ;)

Comment: @feersum a non-zero input will never have preceding zeros.

Comment: @Zgarb they are not valid inputs

Comment: @TRIG I would have added that if there were fewer answer already given for the current set of inputs.

Answer (score 18):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 20 bytes

```
U|sG36ZA13\[BID1]m+g
```

Input is a string enclosed in single quotes. Output is `1` for truthy or `0` for falsy.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=VXxzRzM2WkExM1xbQklEMV1tK2c&input=J2RlZmluZWQn) Or [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=IkBnClV8c0AzNlpBMTNcW0JJRDFdbStnCl12IQ&input=eyctMScgJzEnICcxMjM0JyAnLTQzMjEnICdkZWZpbmVkJyAnZGVGaW5lZCcgJ0ZvdW5kJyAnbm9ubmlsJyAnbm9uLW5pbCcgJ09OJyAnU3VDQ2VzcycgJ1QnICd0cnVlJyAneScgJ1llUycgJzAnICcnICdmYUxTRScgJ2YnICdGYWlsdXJlJyAnbicgJ05hTicgJ25pbCcgJ25vJyAnbm90Zm91bmQnICdub3QtRm91bmQnICdOVUxMJyAnbnVsbHB0cicgJ09GRicgJ3VuRGVmaW5lZCd9).

#### How it works

```
U|s      % Take input implicitly. Interpret as number, absolute value, sum
G36ZA    % Push input again. Convert from base-36
13\      % Modulo 13
[BID1]   % Push array [6 3 8 1]
m        % True if member: gives 1 iff the result from modulo 13 is in the array
+g       % Add, convert to logical. Display implicitly
```

This performs two tests on the input:

1. Try to interpret the input as a number, and detect if it is nonzero. The function used to interpret a string as a number outputs an empty array if it's not possible; and the sum of the entries of an empty array is `0`. So it suffices to try the conversion, take the absolute value, and sum. This gives a positive value if the input contains a nonzero number, and `0` otherwise.
2. Assuming the input string doesn't represent a number, we need to classify it into one of the two given sets. To do this, the input is interpreted as the digits of a number expressed in base-36, using alphabet `'01...9ab...z'`. The base conversion function is case-insensitive and ignores digits not present in the alphabet (in our case, `'-'`). It turns out that the modulo 13 of the resulting number is `1`, `3`, `6` or `8` for the truthy strings, and doesn't give any of those values for the falsy strings. So it can be used as a signature. We thus perform modulo 13 and see if the result is any of those four values. This gives `1` if it is, or `0` otherwise.

The final result should be truthy if any of the two conditions is met, and falsy otherwise. So we add the two numbers resulting from 1 and 2 above and convert to logical, which gives `1` or `0` as standardized truthy/falsy values.

Answer (score 9):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>22</s> <s>24</s> 23 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to edc65*

```
i`^([-1-9sdty]|fo|n?on)
```

The whole code is just a regex. The `` i` `` at the start makes the regex case insensitive.

Outputs `1` for truthy, `0` for falsey.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=aWBeKFstMS05c2R0eV18Zm98bj9vbik&input=Zk91bmQ)

Comment: The `n?on` is great, I'm going to use it. I think you don't need the first `\\`

Comment: @edc65: You're right, I don't, oddly enough.

Comment: Nice trick with `n?on`.

Answer (score 8):

### Batch, 142 bytes

```
@goto l%1 2>nul
:l
:l0
:lfailure
:lfalse
:ln
:lnan
:lnil
:lno
:lnotfound
:lnot-found
:lnull
:lnullptr
:loff
:lundefined
@echo 1
```

Outputs 1 for falsy, nothing for truthy.

Comment: Answers like this make me want to write an automated script that posts questions on Code Review seeded with Code Golf content. *wipes tear*

Comment: This is *amazing*. Even if there might be shorter solutions, I don't care, this is the clear winner.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 35 <s>39</s>

*Edit* using the `n?on` trick, stolen from BusinessCat's answer

*Edit 2* OP clarified, no leading 0s, saved 4 bytes

```js
v=>/^([-1-9dsty]|fo|n?on)/i.test(v)
```

Simply returns `true` or `false`

**Test**

```js
f=v=>/^([-1-9dsty]|fo|n?on)/i.test(v)

trues=[-1,1,1234,-4321,'defined','deFined','Found',
'nonnil','non-nil','ON','SuCCess','T','true','y','YeS']
falses=[0,'','faLSE','f','Failure','n','NaN','nil',
'no','notfound','not-Found','NULL','nullptr','OFF','unDefined']

console.log('TRUE: '+trues.map(x=>f(x)))

console.log('FALSE:' +falses.map(x=>f(x)))
```

Comment: Does removing the `\d` from the regexp and changing to `|v!=0` work?

Comment: How about swapping the `\d` for `1-9`? Provided that feersum's question is accurate, `^([-1-9dsty]|on|fo|non)` should suffice.

Answer (score 4):

## Python, <s>129</s> <s>79</s> 78 bytes

Gotta submit fast!

```
lambda n:n.lower()[:3]in" 0 f n no nil fai fal nan not nul off und".split(" ")
```

True is false and false is true; I have a nice rhyme for this, I really do (not)

Comment: Why the downvote? It seems to work, just true is false and false is true, that's allowed

Comment: You can shorten the string array be writing `' 0 f failure false n nan nil no notfound not-found null nullptr off undefined'.split(' ')`

Comment: @KarlKastor You can actually use `.split()` instead, because the default separator for `split` is whitespace.

Comment: @Skyler I know, but then there's the empty string missing somehow.

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 111 bytes

```python
def b(s):s=s.lower();return s!='no'and not sum(map(ord,s))in[0,48,323,744,523,877,110,785,443,922,315,317,946]
```

Tests on sum of ASCII values, extra check for `no` since `on` has the same value.

- Edit1: forgot to test on integer values. Now checking for false inputs

Comment: @edc65 the first answer didn't, now checking for false and including `ord('0')` does

Comment: `lambda s:s.lower()!='no'and sum(map(ord,s.lower()))in[0,48,323,744,523,877,110,785,443,922,315,317,946]>1` I haven't tested it though.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>83</s> 75 bytes

```
import re
def f(s):return re.search(r'^([-1-9dsty]|fo|n?on)',s.lower()).pos
```

Returns 0 on success, AttributeError on failure.

Now using edc85's regex to save 8 bytes.

Comment: Ah yes, the good old "explode the program when it fails the test" approach. I love seeing comments like "we couldn't have reached here with invalid arguments" :-)

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```
$args[0]-match'^([-1-9dsty]|fo|n?on)'
```

Presumes that the answer to @feersum's question is "No, truthy integers may not start with a `0`."

Port of @edc65's [regex JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89350/42963), with my own `1-9` substitution instead of `\d`. Uses @BusinessCat's [`n?on` trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89358/42963) to golf further.

Outputs literal Boolean `$true` or `$false` values, which when left on the pipeline and sent through an implicit `Write-Output` at the end of execution results in `True` or `False` being printed to the console.

---

If the answer is "Yes, truthy integers can start with `0`," then the following changes need to be made for **<s>51</s> 49 bytes**

```
param($n)$n-ne0-and$n-match'^([-\ddsty]|fo|n?on)'
```

---

If you don't like regex, go for PowerShell v3+ and the following at **107 bytes**

```
param($n)$n-and$n-notin-split'0 f failure false n nan nil no notfound not-found null nullptr off undefined'
```

This takes the string of falsey values, `-split`s them on whitespace, and uses the `-notin` operator to check the input `$n` against that array of strings (which is, by default, case-insensitive). Requires the `$n-and` to check against the empty string.

Comment: You don't need parentheses to use alternation in regex: `'^[-1-9dsty]|fo|n?on'`  :)

Comment: @briantist Without the parens, it matches `notfound` and `not-found` because of the `fo`.

Comment: D'oh, you're right. You could do `^[-1-9dsty]|^fo|^n?on` but that's the same number of chars and less clear.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 50 bytes

```
<?=preg_match('%^([-1-9dsty]|fo|n?on)%i',$argv[1])
```

prints `1` for truthy, nothing for falsy

tried to come up with a different solution, but the shortest regex for falsy is 3 bytes longer than that for truthy: `%^(0|fa|f?$|n(?!on)|of|u)%i`

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 32 bytes

```sh
grep -Pi '^([-1-9dsty]|fo|n?on)'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5NawIxGITv8ytyKNoeAq56KSx6UHNa1sK2h1IqBPJGA@GN5INia3/7drfKDPOcZpjvdOq/Ts6TiKSN0DBB/PTHSGchX5yYHh4/ZCWfTcqXz6sNV14Hfpr2v5OVrOv6QWPM9dBi6mWFQfPFEnK5mFcwZB2TGaj@qUJhAw7Mzo@QI/cturLZUEp4RY6FcME7dZgBVjfdDhZKO18igdHqFrfy4Gzve1neltu3pgEX7885Yq8UCm/vF6z2ifAH)

Outputs via exit code; 0 is truthy, 1 is falsey

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 83 bytes

```
lambda x:x.lower()[:3]in['fou','non','on']or x[:1].lower()in'dsty-123456789'and''<x
```

https://repl.it/ClgO/1

Comment: Don´t the `in`s include non-empty?

Comment: @Titus I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: What is `x[:1]` for an empty string? Does `in` return false in that case? If so, you should be able to drop the `and''<x`

Comment: @Titus, I see what you mean. I had the same thought at first, but `''[:1] in 'abc'` evaluates to true.