# Is it true or false?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

I cannot believe that this hasn't been done before but I may be wrong. If so, just close as dupe.

This challenge is very similar to [Is it truthy or falsy?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/89342/66833) but, IMO, isn't close enough to be a dupe. That has predefined "falsy" variables that all languages must use, some of which aren't even falsy; this uses your own falsy values.

Your task is to take an input, evaluate it and output whether it is truthy or falsy *in your language*.

The "evaluate" part is just so that the input isn't always a string containing the input. For example an input of `0` would be falsy in almost all languages even if `"0"` is truthy. It simply means, "convert it into its native type"

## Input

Anything. This can be taken from STDIN or as command line arguments.

## Output

Its truthy or falsy value *in your language*. This should be preferably be denoted by `true/false` or `1/0`. If not, please state what is the output for each.

For example, `1`, `"hello"` and `[0,2]` are all truthy in Python but the third isn't in MATL (? Correct me if wrong)

## Rules

- There must be 2 unique identifiers for truthy and falsy. You can't just say `numbers are true and symbols are false`
- Submissions must be **full programs**
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) but I have a feeling that a challenge this trivial might become a catalogue so if that happens, I will update the body to contain normal catalogue rules.
- Of course, builtins are allowed but must be part of a full program. For example, `bool` isn't a valid answer in Python.

Good luck!

Comment: This is so trivial it's unbelievable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it truthy or falsy?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89342/is-it-truthy-or-falsy)

Comment: It isn't a duplicate, and I don't think it's closeable under our current rules (if it does, "unclear" would be the only reasonable choice; because the challenge doesn't explain how it works for languages that don't have a Boolean-equivalent, such as Prolog, Incident, and Three Star Programmer). That said, it might be worth a meta post about what we should do with extremely-trivial-in-practical-language challenges like this.

Comment: Why full programs only?

Comment: [Brainfuck, 10 bytes: `,[[-]+>]<.`](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJzpaN1bbLtZG7/9/RQA "brainfuck – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>3</s> 2 bytes

```
o
```

Needs the `-d` flag.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@5///79ScUlRZl66koJuCgA)

Comment: Beat me to it; I've really gotta get my brain thinking in Japt over JS 'round here!

Comment: Also `o` with the `-d` flag would work. Though it would still be 3 bytes.

Comment: @powelles, for some reason flags only count as 1 byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 14 bytes

```
({()(<()>)}<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@69RraGpYaOhaadZa2On@f@/kYKlgYKhggEA)

### Explanation

```
(        #Set up a push
 {       #Execute if truthy
  ()     #Create 1 value
  (<()>) #Ensure a 0 to exit the loop
 }
 <>      #Switch stacks
)        #Push the value
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Convex](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex), 2 bytes

```
!!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PK0ut@P9fUfH///8lqcUlmXnpAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 2 bytes

```
¬¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6///QmkNr/v//bwAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation), 1 char, 3 bytes

```
‼
```

Added this because I've never really gotten a use for the `truthy` function, and I wanted to.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P@///UcOe////GwAA)

Comment: It's a full program too, right?

Comment: Of course. You can see that functionality at the TIO.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>4</s>  2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṆṆ
```

Full program returning 1 for Truthy and 0 for Falsy.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@294aN2hzfb///@PjgUA)**

#### How?

```
ṆṆ - Main link: x
Ṇ  - non-vectorising logical not
 Ṇ - non-vectorising logical not
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
print(input()and 1>0or 0>1)
```

Less trivial than just `print(bool(input()))`. String input must be given in quotes as per Python 2 requirements.

-1 byte thanks to ovs

Comment: `print(input()and 1>0or 0>1)` for 27 bytes

Comment: Wouldn't `print(input()!=0)` work as well?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder thus would give a false positive for `[]`

Comment: @ovs ooo, nice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 6 bytes

```
i=>!!i
```

Comment: OP wants a full program, not a funciton.

Comment: `alert(!!prompt())` is more valid.

Comment: @Stephen, OP is wrong!